# Add twitter glyphicon from code behind

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

This works when adding an icon to a button where static markup is possible

```
<button id="LoginButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>  Login</button>
```

But where it has to be generated from code-behind I can't find a way of adding it - I thought this would work, but no...

```
Dim ViewIcon As New HtmlGenericControl("span")
                        With ViewIcon
                            .Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-new-window")
                        End With

                        Dim ViewButton As New Button
                        With ViewButton
                            .ID = "DocumentViewButton_" & Row("Document_ID")
                            .CssClass = "btn btn-success"
                            .Text = "View"
                            .ToolTip = "View the Document"
                            .Controls.Add(ViewIcon)
                        End With
                        AddHandler ViewButton.Click, AddressOf ViewDocument
```

But it just renders like this

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DocumentViewButton_4" value="View" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentViewButton_4" title="View the Document" class="btn btn-success" />
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems changing Button to LinkButton works

```
 Dim ViewIcon As New HtmlGenericControl("span")
                        With ViewIcon
                            .Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-new-window")
                            .InnerHtml = "  View"
                        End With

                        Dim ViewButton As New LinkButton
                        With ViewButton
                            .ID = "DocumentViewButton_" & Row("Document_ID")
                            .CssClass = "btn btn-success"
                            .ToolTip = "View the Document"
                            .Controls.Add(ViewIcon)
                        End With
                        AddHandler ViewButton.Click, AddressOf ViewDocument
```